# SQL запрос из C# не работает: "Не удалось включить ограничения."

Tags: c#, mysql, phpmyadmin

Делаю один и тот же запрос из phpMyAdmin и из c# программы, но результат разный.

Вот код:

```
queryString = @"SELECT *
                FROM `citations`
                ORDER BY `citation_id`
                LIMIT 0, 30";
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection())
{
    con.ConnectionString = mysqlCSB.ConnectionString;
    MySqlCommand com new MySqlCommand(queryString, con);
    try 
    {
        con.Open();
        using (MySqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader()) dt.Load(dr);
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

В phpMyAdmin все работает и появляется результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А шарп швыряется исключением:

> Не удалось включить ограничения. По меньшей мере одна строка содержит
>   значение, нарушающее ограничения по отсутствию пустых значений,
>   уникальности или внешним ключам.

К БД коннектится, до этой части кода выполняются другие запросы, но к другим таблицам. Текст исключения мне ни о чем не говорит. Помогите!

Comment: Добавьте текст ошибки в вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Как я понял, dt это DataTable. Тогда наверное есть ещё и ds как DataSet.
Можно сделать `ds.EnforceConstraints = false;` перед загрузкой записей, тем самым отключив все заданные ограничения по всем таблицам.

Answer (score 0):

Это не ошибка SQL. Смотрите значение результат вызова `dt.GetErrors()`